# Java "Object" to "?"

Tags: java, generics

I was trying to change a generic Map

```
private final Map<String, Object> dataObject;
```

to

```
private final Map<String, ?> dataObject;
```

The getter changes from

```
public Map<String, Object> getDataObject() {
  return dataObject;
}
```

to

```
public Map<String, ?> getDataObject() {
  return dataObject;
}
```

but the setter:

```
public void addDataObject(final String key, final Object value) {
  dataObject.put(key, value);
}
```

can't be configured without error any idea? or am I doing wrong trying to use the "?" generic

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024097/wildcard-generic-setter-and-getter-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameterize your class instead of using a wildcard:

```
class Container<T> {
  private final Map<String, T> dataObject;

  public Map<String, T> getDataObject() {
    return dataObject;
  }

  public void addDataObject(final String key, final T value) {
    dataObject.put(key, value);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the map was actually a `Map<String,String>` then your could call `addDataObject("key", Integer.valueOf(1972))` and that would be bad. So `dataObject` must remain as it is. You could change `getDataObject`, but that probably wouldn't help and leave client code having to deal with wildcards which is usually frowned upon.

Answer (score -1):

you have already put final modifier before dataObject .. how could you change the value of final variable using set method ???? (not possible it is against the definition of final ).

you can change your code like this  -

```
private final Map<String, ? super Object> dataObject=null;
```

Comment: it's not a problem of "final", you can remove it, the thing is public void addDataObject(final String key, ? value) {
    dataObject.put(key, value);
  } is not valid

Comment: As much as my knowledge when you use wild card.. java prevent you to add any object.
it will be work if you change code like this -
private final Map<String, ? super Object> dataObject=null;